# Magento 2 Display minimal price without tax

Tags: magento2, tax

Magento 2
We display product prices both with and without tax in frontend.
By default minimum price and old price is rendered including tax but I have to display minimal price WITHOUT tax.

Any ideas where or how to can change this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Posted a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no perfect way to do it, best solution I have found is to override the template where the price rendering is happening and use the base amount instead of full amount for "As low as".

**My/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<?php
if ($block->getDisplayLabel() != 'As low as') {
    $price = $block->getDisplayValue();
}
else {
    $price = $block->getAmount()->getBaseAmount();
}
?>

<span class="price-container <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
    <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $price; ?>"
        data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($price, (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try asap

Comment: I want to add condition,if condition satisfy then display including price else excluding price.So please help me to do this.